# Python wrapper get wrapped object

Tags: python, wrapper, magic-methods

I do have a wrapperclass for a specific object giving it some extra methods.
However this object (wrapped or not) is often passed as an argument. In this case I want to past the original (wrapped) object allways.

Is there a way (I guess magic method) to overwrite what is coming back if I do the following in print:

```
class Foo:
    pass

C = Foo()
print(C)
```

I do now that this is actually calling `__repr__` (which needs to be a str). If I do the same for a function call

```
def Bar(obj):
    pass
```

does get Bar a string or the actual class here?

How I wrap the object:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj
   
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        orig_attr = self._obj.__getattribute__(attr)
        if callable(orig_attr):

            def hooked(*args, **kwargs):
                result = orig_attr(*args, **kwargs)
                # prevent wrapped_class from becoming unwrapped
                if result == self._obj:
                    return self
                return result

            return hooked
        else:
            return orig_attr
```

So if do:

```
C_wrapped = Wrapper(C)
```

and than

```
Bar(C_wrapped)
```

if would actually have it to act as

```
Bar(C)
```

even if pass `C_wrapped`

Comment: FWIW, `print(...)` triggers `__str__`, not `__repr__`.  `__repr__` is only triggered if the object is within a printed container

Comment: Of course `bar` gets `obj`, not the string representation of `obj` (that would be pretty useless, wouldn't it?)

Comment: Anyway this question is a bit unclear. Are you asking about [decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)?

Comment: This isn't at all clear. You want to wrap your objects and then have your code automatically ignore the wrappers? Why?

Comment: I am unsure what I am looking for. Top level i want the behaviour as stated at the last part of the question. Passing the wrapped object as argument allways, independendly if i pass the original object or the wrapped object.

Comment: I guess my wrapping is not perfect. The function Bar does not understand the wrapped object and throws an error because it behavious different.

Comment: It might also be a solution if my wrapping is more "complete".

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is that the function Bar (or object in my case) needs to check if it gets a wrapped or unwrapped object. If it is wrapped, Bar unwraps it.
The downside is this induces coupling.